# Почему вместо русского языка кракозябры?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, кодировка, apache2

Только учусь делать сайт с помощью `python`. И решил сделать страницу с русским языком, но вышли кракозябры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю что проблема с кодировкой(скорее всего), вот только не пойму где и как исправить...

### Код:

```
#!/Python380/python 
print("Content-type: text / html")
print(
"""
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Проба с Python</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><b>Привет</b></h1>
    </body>
</html>
"""
)
```

Кодировка файла python:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверьте, в какой кодировке у вас файл с исходным кодом на python. Вангую, `cp1251`. Ну и еще не совсем понятно, почему вывод html-кода происходит через `print`? Вы какой-то фреймворк используете? Или просто статичный код?

Comment: @cauf, спешу Вас огрочит: `UTF-8`(в вопросе добавил скрин)

Comment: Я дополнил коммент. перечитайте

Comment: @cauf, использую просто код `python` поставил себе задачу написать небольшой сайт на чистом `python` без всяки фрэймворков

Comment: А как ваш вывод `print` попадает в браузер? Какая ОС?

Comment: @cauf, код разместил на локальном `apache` сервере в папке `htdocs`. Сервер размещён на `Windows 10`

Comment: А `print` судя по всему просто передаёт данные в браузер, после чего он обрабатывает. Браузер: `Google Chrome`

Comment: Вот здесь у вас и проблема. Канал `stdout` у винды работает на cp866 (cp1251 - есл перенастраивали кодовую страницу). Передавая текст страницы через `print`, вы приводите его к системной кодировке. Советую генерировать статичный текстовый файл и командой системной передавать на запуск в апач

Comment: Так, и как это исправить?

Comment: дополнил коммент

Comment: @cauf, подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку как это сделать? Просто несовсем врубаюсь как это сделать

Comment: просто записывайте код в какой-то файл на диске с указанием целевой кодировки. Делается это при открытии файла, например так: `open('path\to\file.html', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')`, после чего передавайте путь к файлу в апач для отображения статичной странички (к сожалению я не в курсе как апач работает - тут придется покурить документацию самостоятельно).

Comment: Мда... Ну и мороки с этим XD Ну да ладно, буду тогда рыться)

Comment: Собрал итоговую инфу в виде ответа. Если она вам помогла - отметьте ответ как решение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116301/discussion-between-dgdays-and-cauf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На Хабре дали такой ответ:

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

После него всё стало работать

Answer (score 3):

Как выяснилось в комментариях, автор вопроса использует Windows 10 для запуска кода. Так как канал `stdout` у Windows работает на кодировке `cp866` (`cp1251` - если была перенастроена кодовая страница), передавая текст страницы через `print`, вы приводите его к системной кодировке. Именно из-за несоответствия содержимого тега `meta` и кодировки, в которой код страницы попадает на сервер, вы и получаете кракозябры.

Как один из вариантов решения данной проблемы, могу посоветовать записывать код страницы в какой-то файл на диске с указанием целевой кодировки. Делается это при открытии файла, например так:

```py
raw_html = """
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Проба с Python</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><b>Привет</b></h1>
    </body>
</html>
"""

with open('path\to\file.html', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as page_file:
    page_file.write(raw_html)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Ещё 2 дня подожду с принятием ответа, может дадут более удобный способ)